# What is the Python way to express a GREL line that is creating as many tags as needed in an XML document?

Tags: python, xml, csv, openrefine, grel

I'm using Open Refine to do something that I KNOW Python can do.  I'm using it to convert a csv into an XML metadata document.  I can figure out most of it, but the one thing that trips me up, is this GREL line:

```
{{forEach(cells["subjectTopicsLocal"].value.split('; '), v, '<subject authority="local"><topic>'+v.escape("xml")+'</topic></subject>')}}
```

What this does, is beautiful for me.  I've got a "subject" field in my Excel spreadsheet.  My volunteers enter keywords, separated with a "; ".  I don't know how many keywords they'll come up with, and sometimes there is only one.  That GREL line creates a new `<subject authority="local"><topic></topic></subject>` for each term created, and of course slides it into the field.

I know there has to be a Python expression that can do this.  Could someone recommend best practice for this?  I'd appreciate it!

Comment: The equivalent Jython expression to use with OpenRefine or just a generic Python code snippet? It's basically just a list comprehension `['<subject authority="local"><topic>'+escape(v)+'</topic></subject>') for v in split(value,'; ')]`

Comment: I'm really just looking for a way to do it with a Python script so I can fold it into some other defs I have and do several things at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to use 'split' in Python to convert the string from your subject field into a Python list, and then you can iterate over the list.

So assuming you've read the content of the 'subject' field from a line in your csv/excel document already and assigned it to a string variable 'subj' you could do something like:

```
subjList = subj.split(";")
for subject in subjList:
  #do what you need to do to output 'subject' in an xml element here
```

Answer (score 0):

This Python expression is the equivalent to your GREL expression:

```
['<subject authority="local"><topic>'+escape(v)+'</topic></subject>') for v in split(value,'; ')]
```

It will create an array of XML snippets containing your subjects. It assumes that you've created or imported an appropriate `escape` function, such as

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
```